# DELETE FROM 2 tables with JOIN (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELETE `table1`, `table2` FROM `table1` JOIN `table2` ON table2.col = table1.id WHERE table1.id = 1
```

If in table2 no result with table2.col = table1.id then it sql query doesn't work. If table2 has row with col = table.id then it works perfectly. How to remake it? I need to delete row fom table1 even if in table2 row with table.col = table1.id doesn't exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to delete from table1 no matter what, then why join to table2 at all?

Comment: @TabAlleman He also wants to delete the row from table2 if it's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
DELETE `table1`, `table2` 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table2.col = table1.id 
WHERE table1.id = 1
```

The general rule is that a `DELETE` query will delete the same rows that would be returned if you did a `SELECT` query with the same parameters. Since you would use a `LEFT JOIN` in a `SELECT` to get rows from `table1` that have no match in `table2`, you have to do the same thing with `DELETE`.

This general rule is also helpful if you want to test a `DELETE` safely. Perform the corresponding `SELECT`, and make sure it returns only the rows you want to delete.

Comment: Nice! Thank you and thanks to all. I can accept your answer after 8 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a LEFT JOIN in other to achieve this:

```
DELETE `table1`, `table2` 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` 
ON table2.col = table1.id WHERE table1.id = 1
```

Take a look here for further documentation:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this using the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
DELETE `table1`, `table2` 
FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table2.col = table1.id WHERE table1.id = 1
```